# In Sql Server is the object_id of an object subject to change?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know if in a database in Sql Server 2008 (would also want to know what the difference is there for 2005 and 2000 then) would have a changed object_id for a table for any reason.

Ex. does altering a table change that id by dropping and creating and under what circumstances it chooses to alter a table that way if any as opposed to any other way of altering a table.

I haven't been able to find anything on the web that's very concrete so to speak, like a white paper or msdn article. I found just this conversation: http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/5918/167487.aspx

At first the conversation is basically "no" and then it seems to do a 180. I'm also looking for a legitimate citation for any answer. I'm not that interested in experimentation in front of a real Sql Server design tidbit in case there are strange circumstances in which the behavior changes. For example, maybe it drops and recreates to change a table but only if it is empty; but if it has data it will not change id... etc. I can see how someone might come up with an answer that is seemingly correct but incomplete and not the whole story by doing that.

Apologies in advance for the long winded, possibly insufficiently descriptive, and picky nature of this question.

Comment: What about your solution requires the persistence of the object_id?  There may be a different way to go about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That thread doesn't seem to do an 180 as far as I can see. The example of altering the identity property in SSMS isn't an `alter table` operation SSMS will drop and recreate the table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object_id is allocated at the time of object creation. The only time it will change is if the object is recreated.

Some of the things that SSMS does behind the scenes actually involve dropping and recreating tables *(in some cases, possibly even without having to)*.  If you add a column to the middle of a table for example, it needs to drop and recreate - hence a new object_id.

In any case, you should never persist an object_id from the database anywhere, just query it again each time using `object_id([objectname])`

Comment: "In any case, you should never persist an object_id from the database anywhere" - Sounds like what I really needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

one way the object_Id *might* be persisted, unwittingly, is if some "clever" programmer has created an auditTrail table that uses objectids instead of table names (you decide if this is a clever idea or not). When data changes, the object_id() and identity columns are stored.

The question above, which I believe has not yet been answered, is whether that object_id value will in fact persist across things like restoring the database to another server, upgrading sql server versions, fail-over of database across different cluster hosts, etc.

whether it is a good idea to try using a persisted value of the object_id is another question (which I believe has been answered above with "NO; not a good idea"). If SSMS drops and recreates tables behind the scenes, that right there is sufficient reason to NOT use object_id

Comment: There's a fine line between *clever* and *over engineered* and *bat shit crazy*

Comment: There are reasons one may need to know the answer.  And it seems nobody has answered.  
I need to know if the forensic data captured by system monitoring tools during a problem is reliable given only object numbers were captured and a db restore had to be done to recover.  Can I reliably query the object names now that the database has been restored or is it like reading a table without an order by clause - it often returns rows in insert order but it can't be relied on.  Small tests indicate it might work but MIGHT isn't definitive and 'might not' could lead to lawsuits.

Answer (score 0):

The object_id will change as SQL Server recreates tables internally. Instead (or in addition), store the database name.